# ways to speed up update postgres to handle high load update on large table? is it ok to set fill factor to 10

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-rds, partitioning

- updating 1 record at a time need 50ms
- but My Update is Taking 2 minutes to update 500 records and single updates take 300-500ms
- full record is 1 million on a single partition.
- the nature of each update is 1 update at a time i can't do it in batches because its in customers end
- records are DELETED after use like a 3-4 months or so.
  write speed is more important to the customer

things i did so far

- Partitioning because my data can grow 10 million
- indexing and removing indexes

what i using.

- i'm using db t2.micro but moving to db m5.large doesn't improve much
  i guess its just 30 seconds faster if i leave fill factor to 100 but decreasing it a lot improved my update performance
- rds
- postgres 12.3

would it be safe to set  FILLFACTOR = 10-20?

Comment: "*updating 1 record at a time need 50ms*" that sounds as if you have an awfully slow disk or I/O system.

Comment: Perhaps show your table and index definitions and the statements in question. How is the I/O subsystem doing while performance is bad?

Comment: the cpu is mostly affected when i have it fillfactor 100 i barely can handle large request. i've isolated it on testing tables with or without partition the ms is 300ms-800ms, removing indexes improves speed..my personal computer is also taking the same amount of time regardless over a million records. but io is slightly better in rds..two things i gained by setting the fill factor to 10-20 the cpu usage and update speed is better. my table consist of 11 columns and users are updating the exact row with unique id.

Comment: "updating 1 record at a time need 50ms speed for update...and single updates take 300-500ms"  I don't understand what this is trying to say.  An update takes 10 times longer than itself?

Comment: updating 1 row takes 500ms but setting it to fillfactor=10 made it fast but what is the consequence or do i need to tune the table more?